# FFmpeg / imagemagick Cut image top and bottom

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, imagemagick, image-editing

I am creating an image like this:

```
ffmpeg -i chapter_Border.jpg -vf scale=220x176 chapter_Border.jpg -y';
```

how can I cut 15.5px from the bottom and 15.5px from the top of the image so that the image has a height of 145px.

Answer (score 1):

**Using imagemagick:**

Get the size of the image:

```
identify img.jpg
# img.jpg JPEG 1024x768 1024x768+0+0 8-bit sRGB 29.2KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Crop a part of `img.jpg` and save it to `new.jpg`:

```
convert img.jpg -crop 220x145+0+16 new.jpg
# 220x145 is the new size. +0+16 is the X,Y position (upper left corner)
```

I don't think that half-pixels are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -i chapter_Border.jpg -vf scale=220x176,crop=iw:145 chapter_Border.jpg -y
```

Comment: How can I retain the source image dpi and quality? By default it seems to convert to 96 dpi.

Comment: Images only have resolution. DPI relates to printing and is just a metadata in image files. Something like exiftool should be able to change it.

Comment: I ended up using [jpegtran](https://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) which allowed me to crop losslessly and helped retain both the dpi and quality of the image.

Comment: Encoding quality can be retained in ffmpeg by setting the `-q` value e.g. `-q:v 1`